# style-resources-loader does not inject code

Tags: webpack, sass

[image: errormsg, variable was not injected]

So basically I followed [instructions](https://github.com/yenshih/style-resources-loader) and the thing simply does not work like the loader was not even installed. Loader is installed correctly. Relative paths are specified correctly.

The loader chain looks like this:

```js
      {
        test: /\.s?css$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: [   
          inDevelopment ? 'style-loader': { 
            loader: MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader
          },
          { loader: 'css-loader',
            options: {
              modules: {
                localIdentName: '[hash:base64:4]'
              }
            }
          },
          { loader: 'postcss-loader' },
          { loader: 'sass-loader' },
          { 
            loader: 'style-resources-loader',
            options: {
              patterns: [
                './dev/App/styles/**/*.scss', 
                './dev/App/styles/config.scss' 
              ]
            }
          }
        ]
      }
```

Any ideas what i may be doing wrong?

Comment: Does not add all files, only configuration mixins etc.
and only here. Delete this line - './dev/App/styles/**/*.scss'

Comment: Hi. I understand that if I mess here I will get a lot of redundant css prepended to each `.scss`-file in the project. But I see no way it can cause the described problem.

Comment: In the documentation you have exactly what should be given - [style-resources-loader](https://github.com/yenshih/style-resources-loader#usage). In js files, simply import the rest of the code - `import '../scss/modules/_article.scss';` I use a different library but it's practically a 1:1 copy, [see this code](https://github.com/tomik23/photoBlog/blob/master/config/webpack.prod.js#L156)

Comment: I prepared an example using [style-resources-loader](https://github.com/tomik23/webpack-babel-corejs/tree/style-resources-loader)

Comment: > In the documentation you have exactly what should be given

I'm afraid, I don't understand what you tried to convey.

Comment: In the documentation in the "Usage" section you have exactly described what files should be there [variables, mixins, funciton, e.g.]
Take a look at my example I prepared [style-resources-loader](https://github.com/tomik23/webpack-babel-corejs/tree/style-resources-loader)
Follow this code to see exactly what it is about.

Answer (score 0):

Solved. The problem was caused by incorrect glob pattern, at least in context of node's `glob` implementation. While figuring out the desired glob pattern I used [this](https://globster.xyz/?q=%2Fdev%2FApp%2Fstyles%2F*%2F**%2F*.scss&f=%2Fdev%2FApp%2Fstyles%2Ffunctions%2Fcolor.scss%2C%2Fdev%2FApp%2Fstyles%2Ftest.scss) resource. And because of either different implementation or false negatives, the correct pattern was dismissed.

Then I sticked to node glob documentation and ended up with the following pattern that works exactly as expected:

```js
'./dev/App/styles/*/**/*.scss'
```

Conclusion: always prefer official documentation;